# Access Help File .CHM from Resources Visual C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, chm

I am trying to access the help file that I made in the resource of the visual studio. The way that I access it is using:

```
Help.ShowHelp(this, "D:\TEs\TEs\Resources\Manual.chm");
```

This doesn't work when I create an executable file and try it on another computer because there is no file in the TEs directory. 
What is the best way for my programme to always call the help file from the resources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Place your .chm in the same folder as the executable and use a relative path to access it.
Note that your application's working folder may change during execution, so you'll probably want to use a folder relative to the location of `Assembly.GetEntryAssembly()`.

Comment: Is there a way that I can somehow open the chm file from resources? For instance, instead of this D:\TEs\TEs\Resources\Manual.chm, I say current directory\TEs\Resources\Manual.chm?

Comment: You can use any path you like, as long as you ensure that the path exists on target machines. You should be ok as long as you use the same convention in your program code and installer.